# What is the motivation behind defining continuity at isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition, intuition, motivation

The naive conception of a continuous function is that it is a function whose graph can be drawn without lifting your pencil off the page. In introductory analysis, we often define continuity at a point $a$ by requiring that $f$ be defined in a neighbourhood of $a$, and that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$. One reason that this definition is consistent with this intuition is because of the intermediate value theorem:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $c$ is a number that lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there is some $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=c$.

This theorem is intuitively obvious from the "pencil-lifting" conception of continuity, and so the fact that we can prove it from the proper definition of continuity affirms the fact that the definition we have chosen models our intuition.

However, beyond introductory analysis, the definition of continuity is often stated a little differently. We say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if $f$ is defined at $a$ (not necessarily in a neighbourhood of $a$), and that
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in\operatorname{dom}(f):|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon
$$
This definition is equivalent to:

> (i) $a$ is an isolated point of the domain of $f$, or
>
> (ii) $a$ is an accumulation point of the domain of $f$, and $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

My question is: what is the motivation behind adopting the above definition? From the "pencil-lifting" conception of continuity, a function such as $f=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ does not look like it should be continuous, and so it seems that this definition, unlike the previous one, does not model our intuition (at least, it does not model the intuition that we have when are first introduced to continuous functions). It seems that there is something that this definition is something to capture, and that it is also convenient in many respects, but I'm not sure what they are.

Comment: If you take the cruder explanation of saying there is continuity when for all points $y$ close enough to $x$ you have $f(y)$ arbitrarily close to $f(x)$ then with an isolated point there are no other points very close to it apart from itself, and $f(x)-f(x)=0$ so the definition of continuity is met.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of topological space? It basically means a set together with a notion of continuity. Mathematicians like to be able to discuss a wide variety of topological spaces, some of which might have isolated points.  For example, you could say that your set $X = \{(0,0), (1,0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $Y = \{(0,0), (2,0)\}$, ie, they are the same as far as what continuity means on them.  The reason is that there is a homeomorphism (continuous function with continuous inverse) $X \rightarrow Y$ given by $(0,0) \mapsto (0,0)$ and $(1,0) \mapsto (2,0)$.

Comment: Just a question; Is draw without lifting your pen from the paper really a good analogy?  functions like $x^2\cos(1/x)$ are continuous but how to draw it ?

Comment: @JairTaylor: Thanks for responding. I *think* that a topological space is a set where you can define "closeness" via neighbourhoods, but not necessarily "distance" (if you can define "distance', then it is a metric space, I believe). I'm not familiar with a formal definition of topological space. Anyway, if you wish to write an answer that looks at continuity in the broader context of topological spaces, then I would be very happy to see it. I might not fully understand it, but it would definitely benefit others.

Comment: @PaxDaga: It's true that this function, though it can be continuously extended at $0$, cannot reasonably be said to be "drawable". However, this function does satisfy my current intuition for continuity in other ways: for instance, it does not have any abrupt jumps around $0$.

Comment: The function $x\cos(1/x)$  satisfies  the intermediate value theorem but its not continuous (defined to be 0 at 0) in fact there exist functions that are nowhere continuous but satisfy the intermediate value property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just isolated points.  Once you start to consider functions whose domains are not intervals, you have to give up on the pencil-lifting metaphor for continuity.  For instance, consider $\mathbb{R}^\times$, the set of nonzero real numbers.  The function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^\times \to \mathbb{R}^\times$, $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, is continuous, but doesn't satisfy the pencil-lifting criterion.

It's been said that the best definitions are the ones which makes the theorems easy to state and prove.  The definition of continuity that you cite gives theorems like:

- If $f(a) > 0$, then $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$;
- If $A$ is a compact subset of the domain of $f$, then $f(A)$ is a compact subset of the image of $f$;
- same as above with “compact” replaced by “connected”, or “path-connected”

If you want to create exceptions to continuity for isolated points, then these theorems would be weakened.